# html5 input date empty on post php

Tags: php, html, date, input

I'm using the HTML5 input date type. After posting, I see this input empty, and all the other inputs (HTML4 types) are OK.

What could be the reason?

This is my form:

```
<form action="/SGM/index.php?r=manager/addcoach_post" method="post">
        <div class="registerFeildArea2">
            <div class="registerTxtP2">Family name</div>
            <div class="registerFeild">
              <input name="lname" type="text" value="" size="" class="registerFeildValue" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="registerFeildArea">
        <div class="registerTxtP2">First name</div>
            <div class="registerFeild">
              <input name="fname" type="text" value="" size="" class="registerFeildValue" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="registerFeildArea2">
            <div class="registerTxtP2">Address</div>
            <div class="registerFeild">
              <input name="address" type="text" value="" size="" class="registerFeildValue" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="registerFeildArea">
            <div class="registerTxtP2">City</div>
            <div class="registerFeild">
              <input name="city" type="text" value="" size="" class="registerFeildValue" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="registerFeildArea2">
            <div class="registerTxtP2">Birthdate</div>
        <div class="birthDayFeild">
          <input name="bdate" id="meeting" type="date" value="2011-01-13"/>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AddBtn"><input name="Next" type="submit" value="הוסף" class="AddBtnValue" /></div>
    </form>
```

And when I get to the `actionAddcoach_post()`, all the fields are OK except for the bdate.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you using a HTML5 document type (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)?

Comment: Make sure your browser supports it too.

Comment: Can you post whole code of the html file

Comment: I have found my mistake, thanks !

Comment: Please add the answer found or delete your question.